# Need to set an area to display images which restricts their size

Tags: image, resize, thumbnails

I am working on a project showing client testimonials as markers on a google map.

Using server side clustering in SQL and returning a json of field for clusters or markers, which is all working nicely.  Some of the testimonials contain richer content, such as image url or video url.

I am using a .JS file marker with labels to show a text banner under each marker showing the rating e.g. 5 out of 5, but where a customer has supplied us with an image, i need to display the image.  The marker with label code uses CSS styles to set text or image.  I am checking in my Jquery code for a photourl, and if one exists, supplying the right paramters to the marker, however, as the customers have provided these images, they are all of varying dimensions and resoution.  The current code seems to sho the photo's actual size hanging off the marker, i tried adding max-width: 60px; max-height: 60px; width: auto; height: auto; but it had no effect.  is there any way i can use CSS or jquery to reduce the display size of these images, whislt maintaining aspect ratio?

I have a feeling i am going to have to go through the existing stock, create amended files and update the database to point each record to its new path, which i would rather avoid if i can code around it instead.  Once this project is working there will be a big push to get more customer data and i can influence the file saving of future images.

Essentially, I want some code to show an image as thumbnail with max dimensions of about the size of a normal icon on a windows desktop.

Comment: changed tack slightly, to displaying the image in the div with the customers review, which i create dynamically when a link or the map marker is clicked....I found this thread about changing image size by id using a function of area of image: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572170/resize-image-by-area[/link], can i get it to call the function?$(target).click(function () { $("#message").empty(); $("#message").append(msgstring); resizeImgByArea(objectList[index].ReviewID, 50); });

Comment: SOlved it!  i had set the jquery to create the string with the inline stylesheet css code incorrectly using {} not "..."  once i changed it to be style="max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px; width: auto; height: auto;"  not style={max-width: 120px; max-height: 120px; width: auto; height: auto;}  it works as i wanted it to...

Answer (score 0):

Incorrectly using `{}` not `"..."`. Once, I changed it to:

```
style = 
         "max-width: 120px;
          max-height: 120px;
          width: auto;
          height: auto;
         "
not style =
             {
                max-width: 120px;
                max-height: 120px;
                width: auto;
                height: auto;
            }
```

It works as I wanted it to.